# HttpWebRequest to NSUrlConnection/NSUrlSession or HttpClient (with ModerHttpClient lib)

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpwebrequest, nsurlconnection

We have code written in Xamarin Cross Platform that works for Android with Clients tunneling software:

```
           string body = "<rest_access/>";

           byte[] dataByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);

           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint + @"/rest_access");
           request.Method = "POST";
           request.ContentType = "application/xml";
           request.Accept = "application/json";

           var credentials = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
           string encodedCredentials = System.Convert.ToBase64String(credentials);
           request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

           request.ContentLength = dataByte.Length;

           Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();

           stream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);

           try
           {
               HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
               string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();

               dynamic authResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
               //Console.WriteLine("Auth response:\n" + authResponse);

               accessKey = authResponse.rest_access.access_key;

               //Console.WriteLine("kljuc " + accessKey);

               return accessKey;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
               return "Unexpected Error";
           }
```

But when using this same code for iOS application tunnel does not seem to be present.

In their documentation we found:

> Apps built with the Xamarin development platform can access network servers in various ways. AppTunnel with
>   HTTP/S tunneling is supported only as follows:
>   • The app uses the NSURLConnection or NSURLSession APIs exposed to C# through the Xamarin.iOS
>   binding.
>   • The app uses the ModernHttpClient library with NSURLSession. The ModernHttpClient library with
>   CFNetwork will not work.
>   For example, the app initializes the instance of the ModernHttpClient as follows:
>   var httpClient = new HttpClient (new NativeMessageHandler ());

Does this mean that we have to rewrite all methods that used HttpWebRequest in them to now use one of these libs?
If so could I get some link to How to rewrite these so they are acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `HttpClient Implementation` for `Xamarin.iOS` in
[HttpClient Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack#selecting-an-httpclient-stack)

change it to `NSUrlSession` or `Managed`

Comment: We already use NSUrlSession (iOS 7+) for HttpClient Implementation, it was set up as the default.
We will try switching to Managed.